# Change Stripe Subscription Price at end of current period

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a subscription setup for a user that has subscribed to the "pro" plan at $5 per month.

Halfway through the period, they decide they want to downgrade to the "basic" plan at $1 per month.

Current behavior immediately changes the subscription.

Does stripe have the functionality that would allow the actual change of plan to occur when the next billing cycle begins?

This would be similar to the cancel at billing period end when a subscription is cancelled.

From what I can tell, my application might have to handle this logic and make a no proration change close to but not after the billing period change.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the subscription and set `proration_behavior` to `none`. This should keep the same billing cycle and charge the customer $1/month at the start of the next cycle: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update

You could also use Subscription Schedules, though that might be more useful if you had a few different phases to account for instead of a one-off update like this one: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#downgrading-subscriptions

Comment: I think schedules is the answer. I set proration behavior to none, but that has the knock on if they change their "planned" update to a different price point, it will recharge them. IE Was at $5, downgraded to $1 with no proration, but then go back to $5 before the billing cycle ends, they will have been charged $10.